# Why: when i have created a user in mysql with password, i can also login with this user without password

Tags: mysql

when i run this order:

```
mysql>insert into mysql.user(Host,User,Password) values("localhost","test",password("1234"));
  Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.14 sec)
```

Sometimes when i use this order to login:

```
mysql -u test -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

But, when i use:

```
mysql -u test
```

it can be a success login.

I can try this sql orders to solve this problem:

```
 mysql>delete from mysql.user where user='';
 mysql>flush privileges;
```

but i still don't understand why this happens?

In most cases, I just need to use `mysql>flush privileges;`, it can work.

Comment: I think as a general rule, you shouldn't directly insert into the `mysql.user` table.  You should use GRANT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) statements instead.

Comment: do `SHOW GRANTS FOR test@localhost` and you'll see some grants have been made without a password.

Comment: And if you `SHOW DATABASES` while logged in without a password you may see a different set of available databases than if logged in with a password. It is really important to use the `GRANT` syntax correctly to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Further, you need to understand that MySQL logins have 3 parts: user, host, and password, and a single user may have many different combinations of host and password (or no password) which grant access to different resources. Simply setting a password in `mysql.user` does not universally apply it to all granted resources.